# make a class or method for changeOnClick(R.id.old_img, R.drawable.new_img)

Tags: android

Is it possible to define this function or method? (For any number of images or anything that exist in xml)

I need this function:
***changeOnClick(R.id.old_img, R.drawable.new_img);***
If old_img and new_img not be exit, show a message and do fallow commands.

```
final ImageView old_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.old_image);
old_image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                old_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_image);//old_image and new_image are exist in drawable folder
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

I'm building an app that works with many pictures. For shorthand in programming, I wanted a function that is easily usable forever. When I touch one of these photos (old_img), this photo is slightly smaller and change others (new_img).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As long as the function is within the class that is inflating the layout, then yes. You would just declare the function in your ImageView like so:

```
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:onClick="nameofyourfunctionHere"
             />
```

I'm not sure I would declare a specific resource drawable within your function though. I would build the function like so:

```
    public static void changeOnClick(int imageView, int drawableResource){  //old_image means any image on xml

final ImageView old_image = (ImageView) findViewById(imageView);
old_image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                old_image.setImageResource(drawableResource); //old_image and new_image are exist in drawable folder
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

Then within your JAVA code you can declare this for each drawable or an array:

```
    ImageView iv;
        iv.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.default);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                changeOnClick(R.id.imageView, R.drawable.newImage);

            }
        });
```

**EDIT**

If I'm understanding your second post correctly, it sounds like you need a state list drawable. With a state list drawable, when the user clicks on the button/view, the background image changes. You would create an xml file in your drawable folder that looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"//referenced drawable from your drawable folder
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused"//referenced drawable from your drawable folder
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />//referenced drawable from your drawable folder
</selector>
```

Name that button_custom.xml. Then you could use that as your background in your layouts xml file like this.

```
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/custom_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/custom_button"
    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"  />
```

With that, you would get a clickable ImageView that is a button.

Comment: @gadolf Yes that is true but given your question, and without knowing what you're trying to accomplish, this shows that you "CAN" use a function on an ImageView per your question.

Comment: I couldn’t use a function, (your right) but I need a class.

Comment: @gadolf You have to have a class anyways to inflate the layout that holds the ImageView(s). Given your screenshot, I wouldn't declare your first int as "imageView" as that may confuse the IDE. Use something like imgID

Comment: OK. My friend, I just started programming, and my English is not good. I know what you mean, but I'm not still able to do. I modified the question. Codes do you do it?

Comment: @gadolf could you please explain what you are trying to achieve in the end if you were to already have the function you need. Also don't worry about your English, you're doing fine.

Comment: I explained in the lower part

Comment: @gadolf if my answer answered your question, please accept it by clicking the check mark on the left. Thank you :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not properly express my goal. But now I have solved my problem in another way. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @gadolf glad you got it solved. I would post your solution though to help others that may come across this question with the same problem.